# How to add text field in interactive notifications in iOS 8

Tags: ios

I am developing an app. That will have interactive notification.if app gets push notification and app is not running in foreground then user should be able to reply through notification in notification center.I want to add text field to get text from user and reply button to send that text to app.

Any idea how to do? I am able to add buttons through UIMutableNotificationAction class.but could not find way to add text filed.

Comment: As iOS 8 (to my knowledge) hasn't been released yet, you'll have to ask on the Apple Developer forums.

Answer (score 1):

For Xcode6 GM and iOS8 GM version. there is No option to Add Textfield to Interactive **Notification.

```
 NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0)
  @interface UIMutableUserNotificationAction : UIUserNotificationAction
  // The unique identifier for this action.
  @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *identifier;

  // The localized title to display for this action.
  @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
  // How the application should be activated in response to the action.
  @property (nonatomic, assign) UIUserNotificationActivationMode activationMode;
  // Whether this action is secure and should require unlocking before being performed.    If the activation mode is UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground, then the action is considered secure and this property is ignored.
  @property (nonatomic, assign, getter=isAuthenticationRequired) BOOL authenticationRequired;
  // Whether this action should be indicated as destructive when displayed.
  @property (nonatomic, assign, getter=isDestructive) BOOL destructive;
  @end
```

Please refer the below link for More Details:

[UIMutableUserNotificationAction](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIMutableUserNotificationAction_class/index.html)